# In mongodb can we download multiple collections with one command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Now I am using mongoexport command to download a collection and mongodump to download whole db data. Is it possible to download multiple collections with one command?

The command I use to download single collection is as below:

```
mongoexport -h $MONGODB_SERVICE_HOST -d countly -c collection_name -u $MONGODB_USER -p $MONGODB_PASSWORD -o /opt/app-root/src/filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using automating the task by writing bash script like below:-

replace values accordingly.

```
db=<db>
collection_list="<collection1> <collection2> <collection3>"
host=127.0.0.1
port=<port>

out_prefix=/Temp
for collection in $collection_list; do
    echo $collection
    out_dir="${out_prefix}/${db}_${collection}/"
    mkdir -p ${out_dir}
    mongodump --host $host --port $port --collection $collection --db $db --out ${out_dir}
done
```